# What is the radius of convergence of the Sommerfeld expansion for a free fermion gas?

Tags: statistical-mechanics, fermions, approximations, chemical-potential

I'm teaching an undergrad class in statistical mechanics right now, and for my own edification I decided to take the Sommerfeld expansion for the chemical potential of a fermion gas out to higher order.  I used Mathematica and obtained the following series up to $\mathcal{O}(t^{10})$ (where $t = kT/\epsilon_F$):
$$
\frac{\mu}{\epsilon_F} = 1 - \frac{\pi ^2 t^2}{12}-\frac{\pi ^4 t^4}{80}-\frac{247 \pi ^6 t^6}{25920}-\frac{16291 \pi ^8 t^8}{777600}-\frac{1487 \pi ^{10} t^{10}}{15360} - \dots
$$
However, when I plot these successive approximations and compare them to the numerical result, the convergence gets *worse* at finite values of $t$:
[image]

The convergence does seem to improve at smaller values of $t$, though:

[image]

So my questions are:

- Can the Sommerfeld expansion be thought of as a Taylor series in $t$ with some finite radius of expansion?  If so, what is it?
- Or is the Sommerfeld expansion an "asymptotic expansion" in the sense of Stirling's formula, where including "too many terms" at any particular $t$ value will eventually lead to a divergent result?

Any pointers to sources that discuss this would be helpful as well.  Pathria calls this technique an "asymptotic result" but doesn't elaborate and I'm not sure if he means it in the same sense that Stirling's formula is an "asymptotic expansion".

Comment: Not an answer, but you may find useful this paper and its bibliography https://aip.scitation.org/doi/pdf/10.1063/1.1350634

Comment: Note that your expansion parameter is $\pi t$. From your first figure, the expansion seems to break down when $\pi t = 1$, hence $t = 1/\pi$, which suggests a finite radius of convergence. For an asymptotic series, you'd expect factorial growth of the coefficients which is not obvious from the terms listed.

Answer (score 6):

Visually it looks extremely likely that this is an asymptotic series. But the question of why seems very interesting. I'll take a "physicists' definition" of asymptotic series as follows:

An asymptotic series is an approximation for a function $f(x)$ in the form:
$$
f(x)\approx\sum_{n=0}^{N(x)} a_n x^n
$$
Where the best approximation for $f(x)$ comes from only summing a finite number of terms $N$, and $N$ becomes bigger when $x$ is smaller. Often the optimal $N$ is $\sim1/x$. And typically the error after summing the optimal $N$ is $\sim e^{-1/x}$. Thus when $x$ is order $1$, no good approximation is valid.

**If we accept this as the definition of asymptotic series, then this definitely is an asymptotic series and it's pretty easy to show...**

I've allowed myself to skip a bunch of steps by starting from eqn 8.170 in [this link](https://farside.ph.utexas.edu/teaching/sm1/Thermalhtml/node107.html). So far we've done a taylor expansion, which is not yet an asymptotic expansion (and I think probably has an infinite radius of convergence). We're summing over $m$.
$$
-\beta^{-m}\int_{-\beta\mu}^{\infty}\frac{e^x}{(e^x+1)^2}x^m
$$
here we have a function where most of the nonzero values are within a few integers of $0$, and the lower bound of our integral is far from 0 ($\beta\mu\gg1$). So we approximate by setting the lower bound of the integral to $-\infty$, allowing us to analytically solve the integral. This is the approximation that makes this an asymptotic series. The error in this step will be of order
$$
\frac{e^{-\beta\mu}}{(e^{-\beta\mu}+1)^2}(-\beta\mu)^m\approx e^{-\beta\mu}(-\beta\mu)^m
$$
Here we have the first part of our definition - error that is $\sim e^{-1/t}$ (in your notation). We also have the second part, the error increases with $m$, because of the $(-\beta\mu)^m$ part (big number to an increasing power). As for the optimal number of terms being finite, we can see when this error is bigger than the term we're calculating itself (switching over to your notation)

$$
e^{-1/t}(1/t)^m=I_nt^m
$$
$$
e^{-1/t}=I_nt^{2m}
$$
$$
-1/t=2m\log(I_nt)
$$
I'll very naiively assume that $\log(I_nt)$ is $O(1)$ (but negative) and we find that we should stop summing when
$$
m=\frac{1}{2t}
$$
We've satisfied all the parts of the physicist's definition of an asymptotic series.

Answer (score 4):

This is an interesting question that I enjoyed looking into. I think the answer involves a trade-off of two approximations used in the Sommerfield expansion, which I'll now show. Hopefully, this will answer your two questions of how to understand the Sommerfield expansion.

In the Sommerfield expansion one uses the fact that at temperatures far low than the Fermi temperature, the derivative of the Fermi-Dirac distribution ($n_F$) is sharply peaked at the Fermi energy:
\begin{align*}
 - \frac{\partial n_F}{\partial \epsilon} = \frac{\beta/2}{\cosh^2(\beta(\epsilon-\mu)/2)} \to \delta(\mu-\epsilon) \quad\text{as } T \to 0,
\end{align*}
where $\beta$ is inverse temperature and $\mu$ is the chemical potential.
For a smooth function $d(\epsilon)$ with anti-derivative $D(\epsilon)$, we have
\begin{align}
\int_0^\infty d\epsilon \, d(\epsilon) n_F(\epsilon) = - \int_0^\infty d \epsilon \, D(\epsilon) n_F'(\epsilon) = -\sum_i \frac{D^{(i)}(\mu)}{i!}  \int_0^\infty (\epsilon-\mu)^i n_F'(\epsilon)
\end{align}
where I have assumed that $D(0)=0$. In this problem, the relevant function $d$ is the density of states. The idea of the Sommerfield expansion is that we should only need to include a few terms in the series on the  right-hand side at low temperatures; let's refer to truncating this sum as **approx 1**. However, if one included all terms then this expression holds at all temperatures.

Assuming that temperature is low, such that $\beta \mu \gg 1$, then we can make a further approximation to the result above. Namely, we have that
\begin{align*}
\int_0^\infty d\epsilon \,(\epsilon - \mu)^i n_F'(\epsilon) &= - \int_0^\infty \beta^{-i }[ \beta (\epsilon -  \mu)]^i  \frac{\beta/2}{\cosh^2(\beta(\epsilon-\mu)/2)}\\
&= - \frac{\beta^{-i}}{2} \int_{-\beta \mu}^\infty dx\, x^i \frac{1}{\cosh^2(x/2)} \\
&\approx - \frac{\beta^{-i}}{2} \int_{-\infty}^\infty dx\, x^i \frac{1}{\cosh^2(x/2)}.
\end{align*}
Let's refer to this as **approx 2**.
With the final line, we should no longer expect the Sommerfield expansion to hold when $\beta \mu \sim 1$. The approximation is only useful for simplifying the integrals required in the Sommerfield expansion (since it is easier to integrate from $-\infty$ than $-\beta \mu$).

I think this explains why the Sommerfield expansion you provide worsens at higher powers even at temperatures less than the Fermi temperature. Consider the following difference of integrals, closely related to the difference between the exact and approximate integrals in approx 2:
\begin{align*}
I_i = \int_{-1}^\infty dx\, x^i \frac{1}{\cosh^2(x/2)}-\int_{-\infty}^\infty dx\, x^i \frac{1}{\cosh^2(x/2)}.
\end{align*}
Performing this numerically, one finds that the error grows with the power $i $; $I_0\approx-1.1$, $I_1\approx-2.3$, $I_2\approx-6.3$, etc. There is thus a trade-off, whereby including more terms (i.e., higher powers in the expansion of $D(\epsilon)$) improves the accuracy of approx 1, while decreasing the accuracy of approx 2. This is an interesting result that I hadn't noticed before.

One could, of course, avoid ever using approx 2, by performing more complicated integrals (from a quick look, it seems like the integrals can be expressed in terms of hyper geometric functions). However, since the Sommerfield expansion is useful for obtaining analytic results at temperatures far below the Fermi temperature, this doesn't seem particularly worthwhile.

More explicitly answering your two question. 1) Yes it's a Taylor series in the sense of approx 1. 2) No, I can't see why this would be referred to an asymptotic series (though I admit I'm not an expert on this).

Comment: I think you're wrong on the count of it being an asymptotic series (although you admit you weren't sure about this). Visually it looks very likely to be an asymptotic series (which often looks very similar to a taylor series, except that it isn't expected to converge after infinitely many terms). I'll try to write my own answer that addresses this part.